# With the deprecation of Bartik under Drupal 9.5.x, what theme is recommended for CiviCRM?

Tags: theme, drupal-9

Drupal 9.5 has deprecated the Bartik and Seven themes and replaced them with Olivero and Claro as the public and administrator themes respectively. Olivero has various drawbacks, so I want to use another theme. I tried Bootstrap Barrio which seems to meet most needs, but I can't edit profiles - you can't input the field information - the form appears frozen.

In Edge, the developer console yields lots of this error when trying to create a profile

```
Buttons must have discernible text: Element has no title attribute
```

with the following type of element:

```
<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-default-outline" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ng-click="colData.open = true">
```

The same error occurs with Chrome, Opera and Firefox, so it isn't browser related.

This does not happen with Olivero or Claro, but can anyone suggest another theme?

Comment: Claro is working decently (also in combination with shoreditch) as the CiviCRM Backend-theme for us. Dont know much about the theme for public CiviCRM Pages....

Answer (score 1):

What sounds like a straightforward question doesn't really have a good answer. There are four different choices that you can configure as far as "theme" goes with CiviCRM.

That's because there are two different theme configurations for each of the 'front end' and 'administrative' experiences: one for Drupal (or your CMS) and one for CiviCRM, i.e. 2 x 2 = 4.

1. Administrative experience

It seems clear to me that you want to use Claro for the Drupal theme here, since it's now standard and designed for a good admin experience.

For the civicrm theme, the default works reasonably well out of the box, but there are some extra spaces in table rows that can be annoying. It'd be nice to have a civicrm theme that includes some bits to override that annoyance, but for most admin experiences, I'd pick reliability over customization.

2. Front end / visitor

Normally, you'd want to start here with a Drupal theme that matches the rest of your website, if not exactly the same one.

The civicrm theme that you'd want to combine that with depends on which theme you're using, and how much you're willing to customize it.

In the old days, you didn't have a civicrm theme configuration, and even today, many places will just include a bunch of custom css to clean up the places where CiviCRM looks bad.

But now there's a great new "civicrm theme" configuration option, and you can use a different one for the 'front end' vs the 'adminstration' pages.

You might think that if you're using a Drupal bootstrap theme, then using the civicrm eponomous "CiviCRM Bootstrap theme" extension/theme would be a good fit, but in fact, it's often not a good choice - that theme is a fairly opinionated design that's really for a nice admin experience and mostly just confuses your Drupal theme's look and feel (and doesn't care about or want a Drupal bootstrap theme).

My working solution these days is a new civicrm extension/theme that I've published here:

https://github.com/adixon/toronto

It's designed to let a CMS theme do it's work, and just makes up for some of the old CiviCRM stuff that doesn't usually play well (e.g. form layouts, hard-coded font sizes and styles).

The way it works is that it prevents CiviCRM from loading it's own copies of the bootstrap and civicrm stylesheets, and then has a copy of the standard civicrm style sheet with the yucky bits removed.

Most of the time, I've had to add a few more bits for cleaning up it's use with specific themes, so it's more of a starter, but it does work reasonably well out of the box in combination with most bootstrap based Drupal themes.

Note: "toronto" is not a Drupal theme, you won't see it anywhere in Drupal! After installing the extension, try enabling it as the 'civicrm front end theme', on this page:

/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

i.e. Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences

Comment: This look interesting, but I installed and enabled Toronto and installed Bootstrap4, but there seems no way to specify Toronto as a CiviCRM theme. What am I missing?  The only theme that appears to be CiviCRM specific is Danland.

Comment: I kind of wish that the civicrm thing wasn't called a theme since it makes talking about them confusing. See above for some additional explanatory text and how to enable Toronto as a front-end "civicrm theme".

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I ran composer update on my development system and it deleted Toronto giving rise to errors when I ran the CiviCRM database update script.